# Prove the series is absolutely convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $\mathbb C$ with $a_k≠0$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty}⁡a_k=0$.

How do you prove that the series $\sum_{i=0}^∞ a_1 a_2 \cdot\cdot\cdot \,a_i$ is absolutely convergent.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the quotient criterion, that says if the $Limsup(|a_k+1|/|a_k|) < 1 $

Comment: But i seem to get stuck with  $ lim┬(n→∞) (Sup{a_k: k>_n})$ . However I cant figure out how to get past this.

Comment: Yes, and if you let $b_n = a_1a_2\cdots a_n$, what is $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$?

Comment: It is just the last term since every other term cancels.

Comment: So I get $ Lim(sup{a_k+1 : k>n})$

Comment: By your hypothesis what does this term tend to?

Comment: Yeah the limit is 0, so does this end the proof or do I need to show more?

Comment: What is $C?\,\,$

Answer (score 0):

Take $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $k>n\implies |a_k|<1/2.$

For $i\in \Bbb N$ let $b_i=\prod_{j=1}^ia_i.$

Let $B=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i.$

For $j\ge 1$ let $c_j=\prod_{i=1}^j a_{j+n}.\;$ Then $$ j\ge 1 \implies |c_j|<2^{-j}$$ and also $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i=B+b_n\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j.$$